Is it possible to create custom code analyzers for TypeScript?
I want to know if it is possible to create custom code analyzer for TypeScript like you can for C# and VB# with Roslyn? Are there some frameworks/projects I can leverage to do access AST and semantic information?
Are there some tools to support the integration with Visual Studio to see errors from the analyzer in the code editor? Or everything must be written manually as a plugin for VS?
